# warning like : Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useContext , useEffect } from 'react'
import noteContext from '../context/notes/noteContext';
import AddNote from './AddNote';
import NoteItem from './NoteItem';


const Notes = () => {
  const context = useContext(noteContext);
  const { notes, getNotes } = context;
  useEffect(() => {
    getNotes()
  
  }, [])
  
  return (<>
    <AddNote />
    <div className=" row my-3 mx-3">
      <h3>YOUR NOTE</h3>
      {notes.map((note) => {
        return <NoteItem key={note._id} note={note} />
      })}
    </div>
  </>
  )
}


export default Notes;
```

This is the code where i am rendering and using id as key

```
    // API CALL
    const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/notes/fetchallnotes`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "auth-token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoiNjJiNDRmMjIzNWVhZmNkM2FhODRmMTg1In0sImlhdCI6MTY1NTk4NzgyNH0.LRueOf_bDWJB6NJ5jmN-ZQxStPPUt0ppW2G0s5VcRr4"
      },
    });
    const json = await response.json()
    console.log(json);
    setNotes(json);

  }
```

and here i am fetching the notes
it is the not the first time that i am having this problem
this is my whole console error
react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Notes`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
at NoteItem (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:781:68)
at Notes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:923:68)
at div
at Home
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40285:5)
at div
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40218:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39693:5)
at NoteState (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1033:76)
at App

can anyone please tell actually where i am getting error and which file i should share so that you can help me or where i should work on to remove this error

it is showing me error please do help me

Comment: Check `_id` of each note,  you are probably having multiple notes with same id.

Comment: In the `notes` state you apparently have notes with duplicate `id`s. Using the array index should be avoided as much as possible and instead you should spend a bit of time investigating why you've duplicate ids. The answer you accepted *might technically* make the warning go away, but it doesn't address or fix the underlying data issue. Can you edit your post to share the fetched `response` value from your endpoint? Can you also include how that fetch request is called? [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

could you please use `index` instead of `note._id`, because `note._id` may be duplicates, you are receiving a warning, so you can use `index` instead of `note._id`.

```
{notes.map((note, index) => {
  return <NoteItem key={index} note={note} />
})}
```

Comment: This is opposite to the approach the OP should be taking.

Comment: @Ahmad using the index as the key is not a good approach.
have a look at the article. 
https://dev.to/shiv1998/why-not-to-use-index-as-key-in-react-lists-practical-example-3e66#:~:text=We%20all%20have%20heard%20that,memory%20and%20is%20never%20rendered.

Comment: @MuhammadAli I know, but when you don't have  `id` or `unique id`, then you can use `index` as a key, as you can see the docs on [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: actually it is fetching data from mongdb so it do have a uniqu id but i will try your suggestion